# Can a curve represented by a parametric vector-valued function $(u(a),v(a))$ have a tangent at a point $a$ where $u'(a)=v'(a)=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

This question is a follow-up to [this question about a problem in Spivak's Calculus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467151/spivak-ch-12-appendix-problem-9-prove-that-slope-between-two-points-on-parame)

Given differentiable functions $u$ and $v$ defined below, points $P=(u(a),u(b))$ and $Q=(v(a),v(b))$, and a parametric curve $c(t)=(u(t),v(t)), t\in [a,b]$ from $P$ to $Q$, I'd like to investigate if and when there is some point on the curve between $P$ and $Q$ such that the tangent has the same slope as the slope between $P$ and $Q$.

As shown in the linked question, this issue is linked to the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem.

Consider the functions $u,v: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$u(x)=\begin{cases} 0; &x<0 \\ x^2; &x\geq 0,\end{cases}\quad
v(x)=\begin{cases}-x^2;&x< 0\\0;&x\geq 0.\end{cases}$$

Here is a depiction of the parametric curve $c(t)=(u(t),v(t))$ in pink:

[image]

**To cut to the chase, here is my question**

$v'(0)$ and $u'(0)$ are differentiable, and we can differentiate $c(t)$ by differentiating each component function, yet the curve represented by $c(t)$  doesn't seem to be differentiable at $t=0$, where there is a kink. What is the name for this sort of situation and what theorems tell us more about it? I just finished a chapter on Parametric Representation of Curves in Spivak, and the only comment I recall about this situation is that it doesn't make sense to define the tangent line as $c(a)+sc'(a)$ at such a point $a$ where $u'(a)$ and $v'(a)$ are both zero. Does this mean there is never a tangent line at points like this?

**Here is the context in which this question came up for me**

Let $a$ and $b$ in $[-1,1]$.

**Case 1:** $a<b$ in $[0,1]$

The curve is $(t^2,0)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. This corresponds to $y=0$ for $x \geq 0$.

The slope between any two points is always the same, $0$.

If we apply the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to $(a,b)$, we obtain

$$[u(b)-u(a)]v'(c)=[v(b)-v(a)]u'(c)\tag{1}$$

for $c \in (a,b)$.

Since, for $t \in [0,1]$ we have $v'(t)=0$, and $v(t_1)=v(t_2)$ for any $t_1$ and $t_2$ in $[0,1]$, equation $(1)$ is true.

Note that we can divide by $u'(c)$ in $(1)$ to obtain

$$\frac{v'(c)}{u'(c)}=\frac{v(b)-v(a)}{u(b)-u(a)}=0$$

which says that the slope $y'(x)$ of the parametric curve at $c$ equals the slope between the curve evaluated at $a$ and $b$.

**Case 2:** $a<b$ in $[-1,0]$.

The curve is $(0,-t^2)$ for $t \in [-1,0]$. This corresponds to $x=0$ for $y \leq 0$.

The slope between any two distinct points in $[-1,0]$ is either $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Since $u'(t)=0$, and $u(t_1)=u(t_2)$ for any $t_1$ and $t_2$ in $[-1,0]$, equation $(1)$ of Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem is again true.

Note that we can divide by $v'(c)$ to obtain

$$\frac{u'(c)}{v'(c)}=\frac{u(b)-u(a)}{v(b)-v(a)}=0$$

which says that the slope $x'(y)$ of the parametric curve at $c$ equals the slope between the curve evaluated at $a$ and $b$.

**Case 3:** $a<b, a \in [-1,0), b \in (0,1]$

This is the special case and more interesting case.

From the graph above, we can see that the curve has a kink at $(0,0)$. Both $u'(0)$ and $v'(0)$ are $0$.

**I've been studying parametric equations, and I just realized that I am not sure I know how to tell if a curve represented by a parametric equation is differentiable. Each component function is differentiable, but it seems the parametric function is not.
What is the relevant theorem that deals with this issue?**

Anyways, from a visual inspection it seems that given $a$ and $b$, there is no $c$ in between them such that the slope of the curve at $c$ is the same as the slope between the curve at $a$ and the curve at $b$.

However, equation $(1)$ still seems to be true if $c=0$, because $u'(0)=v'(0)=0$.

Comment: Possibly not a duplicate, but [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367256/how-to-tell-whether-a-curve-has-a-regular-parametrization).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3792238/idea-behind-reparameterization-hiding-a-corner-in-single-variable-calculus/3792259#3792259

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean there is never a tangent line at points like this?

Take the example of a straight line $(x(t), y(t)) = (t,t)$ which is smooth everywhere.  Then change the parametrization to

$$(x(t), y(t)) = (t^3,t^3)$$

so that the curve is traced at different speeds.  No part of the original curve is missing.  The speed is given by

$$(x'(t), y'(t)) = 3(t^2,t^2)$$

which means that for $t=0$, the derivative of either component vanishes.  Yet one can still draw the tangent at $(0,0)$ without problem.

---

Such points are sometimes called *singular point of a curve* or *singularity*, here are just a few types of them without being complete:

**Isolated point**: The curve $y^2 = x(x+1)^2$ over the real numbers has an isolated point at $(-1,0)$:  If you change $x$ just a little bit away from $x=-1$, then the curve has no points there because $y^2$ would have to be negative, which is not possible for a real number.

---

**Cusp**: Example is the semi-cubic $y^2 = x^3$ which has a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) at $(0,0)$

[image: cusp at (0,0)]

---

**Multiple point**:  A point where the curve has no unique tangent and is not invertible, accurs because a point is traced out several times.  Example is a lemniscate that has a double-point at the center.

[image: Lemniscate]

---

**Coordinate singularity**: A singularity that's just due to (poor) choice of coordinates.  My example $t\mapsto(t^3,t^3)$ from above is such a case.  The trouble of determining the tangent at $(0,0)$ can be transformed away.

Another example is the Cartesian leaf $x^3+y^3=3xy$ in the usual parametrization $(x,y) = (t,t^2) / (1+t^3)$.  It has a double point at $(0,0)$ which can be reached by $t=0$ and by $t\to\pm\infty$.  Now $\infty$ is no valid real number.  The trouble can be avoided by using a different parametrization.  However, the curve will still have the intrinsic singularity of a double-point at $(0,0)$.

The Cartesian leaf has also a singularity at $t=-1$ where the curve runs towards $(\pm\infty,\mp\infty)$.  This singularity cannot be transformed away in the plane, but we could apply, say, [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) of the plane onto a sphere.  This effectifely adds a point $\infty$ (the north pole), so that it's possible for a curve to be smooth at the north pole.  This is the case for the Cartesian leaf which has the line  $x+y =-1$ as a tangent as $t\to-1^\pm$.  This process is sometimes referred to at as compactification.

[image: Cartesian foil]

One of the most prominent examples of a coordinate singularity is the [Schwarzschild solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) of General Relativity.  It has a coordinate-singularity at $r=r_s$ where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius of the black hole solution.  This singularity can be transformed away, e.g. by [Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates).

Comment: $y^2=x(x+1)^2$ means $y=\pm \sqrt{x} \cdot |x+1|$. How can we evaluate this when $x=-1$ as you say? I agree that $(-1,0)$ solves $y^2=x(x+1)^2$, but how do we reconciliate that equation with $y=\pm \sqrt{x} \cdot |x+1|$?

Comment: Is there a concept of "smoothness" of the parametric representation instead of of the component functions? You've given many interesting examples, but it seems that there is no theorem that tells us to expect such cases based on smoothness considerations of the parametric representation component functions. In my example, $u$ and $v$ are differentiable but $(u,v)$ is not at $(0,0)$. Is this assessment correct?

Comment: @evianpring: $y=\pm\sqrt{x}\cdot |x+1|$ also allows $(-1,0)$. It's true that $\sqrt{-1}$ is not real, but the equation over complex numbers makes sense, and there we have $\sqrt{-1}\cdot |0| = 0$, which happens to be a real number.  If you want to avoid complex number altogether, taking $\sqrt r$ is only possible if $r\geqslant 0$.  The set of $x$'s with that property consists of two connected components: $x\in\{-1\}$ and $x\in[0,\infty)$; so you have two cases.  In the former case, the equation becomes $y^2=0$ which can be solved over the reals without square roots of negative numbers.

Comment: @evianpring: ...so you can use the compressed representation $y=\pm \sqrt{x}\cdot|x+1|$ and have to live with $\sqrt{-1}\cdot0=0$, or you have to distinguish cases.

Comment: @evianpring: $u$ and $v$ are diff'able and so is $(u,v)$ as 1st derivative exists and is even continuous.  The problem is that the curve comes to *"a halt"* at $(0,0)$.  Maybe what you are looking for is [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)?  It requires that some linear function $A$ exists which basically says: The curve around the point of interest looks locally like a line through that point (or like a (hyper)plane in higher dimensionsional curves).  *"Looks like a line when zoomed arbitrarily close"* is maybe the closest we can get.

Comment: all the concepts you mention seem to be over my head at this point. Looks like I'll have to revisit in the future!